# Reentering the US years later with a passport of a different citizenship?

Tags: usa, passports, dual-nationality

When I was younger, I held a visa on my Argentinian passport. I must have entered and exited the US around 6 times with my Argentinian passport.

7 years after last entering the USA,  I now hold an Italian citizenship, and the US visa for my Argentinian passport has expired. Now, I want to travel to the US with my Italian passport because it's very cumbersome and expensive for me to renew my US visa on the Argentinian passport. Can I expect to enter the US without problems with this passport? Would I be breaking any laws or something?

Answer (score 9):

There is no requirement to consistently enter a country with the same (nationality) passport for your entire lifetime. You can enter the USA as an Italian citizen (subject to the normal procedures such as ESTA), without reference to your Argentinian citizenship at all.

Comment: without reference? AFAIR there are questions on the ESTA form asking you if you ever held another country's passport / citizenship. Not answering them truthfully is a crime and can get you banned from entering the US. But mentioning being an Argentinian citizen in addition to being Italian should make no negative difference.

Comment: @JaleDot I believe that question was not present on early versions of the ESTA application.  I do not know whether it was added before or after July 2014, however.