# Applying to US Visa-Waiver program with two passports, one of which is expired

Tags: usa, passports, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, dual-nationality

I am going to travel to USA in December and as Italian citizen I qualify for the Visa-Waiver program (I also meet the other requirements). The thing is that I am also an Argentinian citizen, but my Argentinian passport expired more than 10 years ago. Note that Argentina does not belong to the list of countries in the Visa-Waiver program. I have a couple of questions:

1. When applying for the Visa Waiver program, what should I answer when I am asked if I have a second passport? I *do* have a second nationality, but, precisely speaking, I *do not* have a second passport, since the one I had expired more than 10 years ago.
2. Could it happen that US officials don't let me into the country because I do not have a valid passport of my second nationality, i.e. a valid Argentinian passport?

Comment: Similar to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31400/reentering-the-us-years-later-with-a-passport-of-a-different-citizenship/31401#31401 but no answer to OP’s Q1 in the linked question

Comment: "Precisely speaking, I do not have a second passport": An expired passport is still a passport; it's just not a valid passport.

Comment: @phoog yes, I meant that I do not have a a second _valid_ passport (and I may not have it _at all_, since I moved a lot in the last years and I don't know where it is)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To enter the US under the VWP, you will need an ESTA.

The ESTA form explicitly asks:

> Have you **ever** been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?

(emphasis mine)

So, **yes, you should indicate that you have had an Argentinian passport**, even though it expired.

If you still have the passport, you can fill in all the relevant fields. If you don't have it, as explained in the relevant help section (accessible by hovering on the circled question mark):

[image]

> If you have been issued one of these documents from another country, but you do not remember the passport number of national identification card number and the year of expiration, answer "UNKNOWN" in the passport number field and four zeros "0000" in the year of expiration field.

And **no, there's no reason they would not allow you in because your other passport has expired or you no longer have it**.

Comment: I have a question about your assertion about the other expired passport not blocking entry. Is it possible for someone to have an old passport attached to some unwanted behavior (like an overstay) but a clean, new passport?

Comment: The unwanted behaviour is attached to you, not the passport. The questions about other passports, previous names, etc. help them match people more easily across multiple passports, nationalities, names, etc, but there's enough info for them to find you even without that in many cases. And that's not even counting biometrics...

Comment: @Freiheit an overstay with a different passport may be harder to detect, but in these days of fingerprints and other biometrics, it's probably not much harder to detect.

Comment: Even without biometrics: last name, first name, place of birth, birth date, that's already enough information to make a match in many cases. They may not be sure, but that could be enough to flag a possible offender for secondary inspection to clear or confirm the match.